# Azure B2B - SharePoint and OneDrive integration for guest users

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive, azure-ad-b2b

I have been trying without great luck to sign in Microsoft OneDrive and sync Sharepoint folder with an invited guest gmail account.  I can sign in with the gmail account online to the SharePoint site but when I sync a document library to OneDrive, it is requesting a work/school account.

Isn't B2B designed to allow this as per link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-azureb2b-integration

Thx

Answer (score 0):

•   It is requesting a work/school account because you might not have granted guest access permission to the document library and onedrive account while also enabling external sharing for onedrive and your organization for that guest account.

•   Also, please note that since this is guest invitation sign in, you are required to share the content at folder or site level only. Ensure that any policy is not enabled which blocks accessing/syncing of your organization’s resources to social accounts.

Please refer the below link for details on controlling external sharing as well as the policy setting to prevent sync for Azure B2B: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/b2b-sync#control-external-sharing

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/b2b-sync#policy-setting-to-prevent-b2b-sync

Comment: I have set the external sharing for SharePoint and OneDrive in the admin center to Anyone.  Added the guest as a member in Outlook groups.  Shared a folder to that gmail guest. Tried again no luck.

Comment: Can't login to that link you sent unfortunately

Comment: Have you checked the Azure policy that might be blocking access from social accounts?? Please refer this link for reference : - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/b2b-sync#policy-setting-to-prevent-b2b-sync

Comment: Sorry for late reply. This blocking policy does not exist in my PC.  Still unable to sync guest user

Comment: I would suggest you to please refer this link for guest user accounts to share and sync sharepoint websites through Onedrive. It states clearly that these folders and sites have to be shared at the file and folder level: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/b2b-sync#methods-of-sharing

Comment: Thanks for link.  Shared the folder but when sync with OneDrive for Business, it is giving error "no work or school account found" when signing with gmail guest account created in AAD

Comment: Hi. Managed to sign in using Gmail but the deprecating web-view sign-in support in OneDrive is giving me error that browser or app is insecure. Any advice?

Comment: In the last link you shared it states clearly "It doesn't work when users share by creating an Anyone link (also known as "anonymous access" link or "shareable" link), or when they share with people who have a Microsoft account or other personal account."

Comment: Yes, and its according to Microsoft Official documentation so I think it shouldn't work with personal accounts. As you are able to sign-in using Gmail account, I think you should try that with Onedrive app on your desktop and then check.

Comment: It could not sync

Answer (score 0):

If MFA is enabled on the tenant sharing the content, you may log on using a browser, but can not sync:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/b2b-sync

"Currently the sync client does not support interactive authentication UI when syncing external content. Any policy that would require a sign-in UI such as MFA (multi-factor authentication) or TOU (terms of use) prompt, will prevent the syncing of the external content from that tenant."